# Removing NA value with if else condition and for loop

Tags: r

I am trying to remove the NA value. I know there are other ways to do it but, for practice, I am using this method.

```
revenue <- c(35000, 40000, 60000, NA, 80000, 90000, 56000)
cost <- c(30000, 35000, 50000, 60000, 70000, 50000, 50000)
new_revenue <- c()

for (i in revenue) {if (i != NA) {new_revenue <- c(new_revenue, i)}}
```

But I am getting this error below:

```
Error in if (i != NA) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `!is.na(i)` instead of `i != NA`